# How to parse a path with regex - optional fields

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex: (example here: https://regex101.com/r/dVTUrM/1)

```regex
\/(?<field1>.{4})\/(?<field2>.*?)\/(?<field3>.*?)\/(?<field4>.*?)\/(?<field5>.*?)\/(?<field6>.*)
```

to parse the following text:

```
pyramid:/A49E/18DA-6FAB-4921-8AEB-45A07B162DA5/{E3646FA1-4652-45E9-885A-3756FC574057}/{F1864679-1D9D-4084-B38D-231D793AA15D}/9/abc.tif
```

giving the following result:

```
Group `field1`  9-13    `A49E`
Group `field2`  14-46   `18DA-6FAB-4921-8AEB-45A07B162DA5`
Group `field3`  47-85   `{E3646FA1-4652-45E9-885A-3756FC574057}`
Group `field4`  86-124  `{F1864679-1D9D-4084-B38D-231D793AA15D}`
Group `field5`  125-126 `9`
Group `field6`  127-134 `abc.tif`
```

But if field5 and field 6 are missing:

```
pyramid:/A49E/18DA-6FAB-4921-8AEB-45A07B162DA5/{E3646FA1-4652-45E9-885A-3756FC574057}/{F1864679-1D9D-4084-B38D-231D793AA15D}
```

I would like this to work and for field5 and field6 to be blank.

Is this possible by modifying the regex statement?

Note: only field6 may be missing as well.

Comment: Can you put non-capturing parentheses around the optional bits, and a `?` qualifier? That is, use  `…/(?:(?<field5>.*?)(?:\/(?<field6>.*))?)?` at the end…  Or some variant on this.  You might need to review the greediness of field 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
(?x)^pyramid:
/(?P<field1>[^/]{4})
/(?P<field2>[^/]+)
/(?P<field3>[^/]+)
/(?P<field4>[^/]+)
(?:
    /(?P<field5>[^/]+)
    /(?P<field6>[^/]+)
)?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/y1kfox/1).

Or, in short (without the verbose flag):

```
^pyramid:/(?P<field1>[^/]{4})/(?P<field2>[^/]+)/(?P<field3>[^/]+)/(?P<field4>[^/]+)(?:/(?P<field5>[^/]+)/(?P<field6>[^/]+))?
```

Depending on the programming language / flavour used, you might use other delimiters like `~` so that you don't need to escape the forward slashes anymore. The `(?: ... )` construct is a non capturing group which is made optional with `?` to allow 4 or 6 (but not five!) fields.

Comment: Why not drop the `x` flag and use `[^/]` instead of `[^/\r\n]`?

Comment: @Jordan: You're absolutely right, just copied it from regex101.com and the newline was there to illustrate the different lines though they're not needed in the actual expression.

Comment: @Jordan: Updated to reflect your thoughts.

Comment: I updated it to this: https://regex101.com/r/y1kfox/2 as field6 can be missing or field5 and field6 can be missing... and also the word pyramid can be any string value.

Comment: Ok... not sure why I was having trouble... but this works with my modifications and yours. https://regex101.com/r/y1kfox/3